# Angular js not waiting for $http ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

This is my first angular js application. I am trying to make an http request and get back response.

```
app.service('info',['$http',function($http){

                var details=function (query) {
                            $http({
                            method:'GET',
                            url:'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily',
                            params:{q:query,cnt:8}
                            }).then(function (response){

                            console.log(response.data);
                            return response.data;

                            },function (response){
                                console.log('s');
                            });
                        };

                return {details:details}

            }]);
```

And this is my controller:

```
app.controller("search",['$scope','$routeParams','info',function($scope,$routeParams,info){

            if ($routeParams.param) {
                var d=info.details($routeParams.param);
                    d.then(function (r){
                        console.log("success");
                    },function (e){
                        console.log("fail");
                    });
}]);
```

But on using the it shows "`Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"`.I have read solutions to similar problems here and this was a working solution in many problems, but I don`t get where its going horribly wrong.

Also do explain this statement :

```
return {details:details}
```

Comment: return {details:details} : The info service is returning an object literal with details(name):details(value) ..

Comment: last statement basically makes public your `details` function so you can call it from controller. otherwise it's just a var inside your service function and is inside a closure out of reach due to scoping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your details function, you need to return $http().

```
    var details=function (query) {
      return $http(...);
    };
```